# How can I generate Jasper report without data source in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

Here I only want to pass a custom class or only parameters into a Jasper template, but it seems without data source there only show up a blank pdf file without any layouts.

I guess it is because the default value of `whenNoDataType` in the jrxml is "nopage" but even I set it to

```
whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"
```

There is still nothing shown up there for any detail band, but only the title band.

Can I ask how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it myself

When give a blank data source then it works like a charm

```
// We must have an empty data source to make sure the layout can show up
    // otherwise will have a blank pdf file
    List<Object> emptyList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Object nothing = null;
    emptyList.add(nothing);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource jRBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(emptyList,false); 

    // This is declared inside the spring/jasper-views.xml
    model.put("datasource", jRBeanCollectionDataSource);
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("pdfReport", model);
```